# Get all words that come after specific word

Tags: python

I have a list that contains strings like this :

```
['White Buns (Hot Dog)', ' 2 x Danish (Almond Danish) - A delight with coffee! \nThe best fruit fillings and of coarse butter filled flaky puff pastry.\n']
```

I want to get all the words that come before all words in brackets and the words in brackets too as to get the following:

```
White Buns (Hot Dog)
2 x Danish (Almond Danish)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? I've tried regex but have no idea how to specify (a word in brackets)

Comment: why 2 x is not there in second line?

Comment: my mistake. Should be included

Comment: Say `l1` is the list. you can do the following: `for elem in l1: print(elem[:elem.find(')')+1])`. For this problem, you do not need regex.

Comment: @ggaurav: `elem[:elem.find(')')+1]` will delete any string that does not contain `)`. That may or may not be desirable.

Comment: @dawg Yes. I answered assuming brackets are always there, and actually, questions sounds that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [str.partition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
li=['White Buns (Hot Dog)', ' 2 x Danish (Almond Danish) - A delight with coffee! \nThe best fruit fillings and of coarse butter filled flaky puff pastry.\n']

>>> [''.join(s.partition(')')[:2]) for s in li]
['White Buns (Hot Dog)', ' 2 x Danish (Almond Danish)']
```

Which works regardless if a `')'` is present or not.

Given:

```
li=['No paren in this string...', 
    'Divide me (after) <- please', 
    'More that (1) paren (2) here']

>>> [''.join(s.partition(')')[:2]) for s in li]
['No paren in this string...', 'Divide me (after)', 'More that (1)']
```

If you want to use a regex, use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to find and keep the first part:

```
>>> [re.sub(r'([^)]*[)]).*', r'\1', s) for s in li]
['No paren in this string...', 'Divide me (after)', 'More that (1)']
```

Don't forget the `.*` after the `([^)]*[)])` or `re.sub` just reassembles your string.

Answer (score 2):

To specify parenthensis you can use '\)' (equal to ')') and '\(' (equals to '(')

```
import re #regex lib

pattern = "(.*?)(\(.*?\))"

text =  't2 x Danish (Almond Danish) - A delight with coffee! \nThe best fruit fillings and of coarse butter filled flaky puff pastry.\n'

result = re.search(pattern, text)
print(result[0]) #all string found
print(result[1]) #first group (.*?)
print(result[2]) #second group (\(.*?\))
```

result:

```
t2 x Danish (Almond Danish)
t2 x Danish 
(Almond Danish)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can achieve this

```py
list1 = ['White Buns (Hot Dog)', ' 2 x Danish (Almond Danish) - A delight with coffee! \nThe best fruit fillings and of coarse butter filled flaky puff pastry.\n']

for word in list1:
  for i, letter in enumerate(word):
    if letter == ')':
      b.append(word[0:i+1])
print(b)
```

Output

```
['White Buns (Hot Dog)', ' 2 x Danish (Almond Danish)']
```